# Make Form inactive when Panel appears on screen

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have created a form which contains a panel(pnlOpenItem).When "Non-inventory Non-Taxable" button is clicked the panel appears.I need to make the all the buttons on the form inactive when the panel appears.I have tried "btn.enabled = false" but the background color changes and its not what i want.My code is,

```
Private Sub btnItemNonTaxable_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnItemNonTaxable.Click
    pnlOpenItem.Visible = True
    LabelNonInventory.Text = "Non-Inventory Non-Taxable"
    isOpenItem = True
    chkTax1.Visible = False
    chkTax1.Checked = False
    txtPrice.Focus()
    btnCashDrop.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

This is what my screen looks like,I want to make the all the buttons in the form inactive when the panel appears

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: I think its better if you show a modal form instead of panel. Panels should not be used like that

Comment: @AbZy is there a way to do this using a panel?

Comment: Nothing is impossible in programming, but you should always try to use the right approach so you don't get stuck later on.

Comment: for each component in panel set the enabled property to false except the panel

Comment: One option is to show another transparent panel on top of all controls in the form.

Comment: @Mayur thanks,I have done that but the background colour turns gray and i don't want that

Comment: winforms controls can't be really transparent. Use [this subclassed panel](http://williamsmash.com/posts/transparent-controls-in-winforms). I just tested it and it works

Comment: @AbZy  can you show me the code,I used a panel over the form but i am not being able to show the components in the form.I changed the backcolor to transparent but still it does not work

Comment: Did you see my last comment?

Comment: @AbZy Thanks for the help,I'm a newbie so i don't know how use this in my code...can you please help me out!Thanks in advance